# Добавить блок ко всем статьям кроме первой

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу все статьи из базы так:

```
$allsta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statiya` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($sts= mysql_fetch_assoc($allsta ))
{
echo $sts[text];
}
```

получается что выводятся из базы все статьи.

Но мне нужно чтобы ко всем статьям кроме первой добавляло `</div>`

То есть чтоб разметка у всех кроме первой была следующая:

```
$allsta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statiya` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($sts= mysql_fetch_assoc($allsta ))
{
echo '</div>'.$sts[text].'';
}
```

Статьи выводятся рандомно.

Comment: И уже который раз пишу. Функции `mysql_` **устарели!** Их нельзя использовать.

Comment: Да можно, только ненадежно, опасно, поддерживаются не все фичи сервера и вроде даже есть проблемы с производительностью @Visman зачем вы отговариваете человека, который хочет выстрелить себе в ногу?

Comment: Когда вы дошли уже до такой проблемы, рекомендую начинать пользоваться шаблонизатором

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$allsta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statiya` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$comma = '';
while ($sts= mysql_fetch_assoc($allsta ))
{
   echo $comma . $sts[text] . '';
   $comma = '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$allsta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statiya` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$i = 1;
while ($sts= mysql_fetch_assoc($allsta )) {
    if($i > 1) echo '</div>';
    echo $sts[text];
    $i++;
}
```

Правильней писать так:

```
$allsta = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `statiya` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$allsta->execute();
$st = $allsta->fetchAll();

$i = 1;
foreach($st as $sts) {
    if($i > 1) echo '</div>';
    echo $sts['text'];
    $i++;
}
```